# Is it possible to tamper MAC address of a device within local network through a Router or a proxy?

Tags: networking, router, proxy

Is it possible that the MAC address of a device in a local network be tampered?

Say the device connect to a router, due to technical constraint nothing can be done on the device except for changing DNS/Gateway and WIFI or Ethernet. And I need the device to be treated with a different MAC address.

Is it doable through Router? Or a proxy?

**Update after being down-voted:**

To add more background, I have two device one device is on a list that accept beta firmware update. I know it is based MAC, so I was trying to enable the second device by just tampering the MAC through a Router, which I know is not doable. Thanks for your help.

My question was "is it doable". I did not have the knowledge. Now I know it is not. It is a perfect answer and I learned from it. The question still makes sense to me and would do to whom does not have the knowledge. I cannot see why it is downvoted.

Comment: A mac address is only relevant on the local network.  Once any traffic coming from the device passes through any other network device, the source mac address in the packet changes.  Perhaps [edit] the question and include some backround about why you want to do this, it may help.

Comment: You're talking about MAC address spoofing, which is done on the host, not router. As others have mentioned, MAC addresses only have local significance, so there's no way hosts and nodes beyond your LAN can know the MAC addresses of your network interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other have said, no - because MAC addresses are not routed and only appear on the segment.

That said, they are not tamper proof even if the device is. You could tamper with the MAC address at the switch level, ie its quite practical to insert a bridge which could modify the mac address between the router device.

Another (albeit much harder) way would be to get a device on the network which resonded to ARP requests faster then the router and tricked the device to talk to it, rather then the router, and then forwarded the requests onto the router and translated them back.

Answer (score 0):

When a packet gets to a layer-3 device (router, etc.), the layer-2 frame, which has the source and destination MAC addresses, is stripped off the packet. When the router determines the interface where the packet will exit, it creates a new layer-2 frame, which includes the router MAC address for that interface as the source MAC address, and the next hop MAC address as the destination MAC address.

Layer-2 domains are bounded by layer-3 devices, and nothing from the layer-2 frame (including the original MAC addresses) survives crossing a layer-3 device.